# SpriteKit: Getting node at CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new to swift and IOS development in general. I am trying to get the node at a certain point. The only way I can think of getting it would be to save each node into a array and loop through it and check if the position is equal to CGPoint. Is this the best / only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to get all nodes that intersect with a given CGPoint?

If so, you could simply call`nodes(at p: CGPoint)` which returns you the list of all nodes which intersects with the point:

```
let nodes = nodes(at: myPoint)
```

If your nodes do not overlap, you could use `atPoint(_ p: CGPoint)` which gets the node with the largest z-order:

```
let node = atPoint(myPoint)
```